# AngularJs: Run Directives after View is fully rendered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to all Angular World, and i'm facing a problem managing the directives.

I'm working on a project that uses Tabs, and i want to extend its functionality to handle overflowed tabs when window size is narrower that the width of all my tabs, so i need to calculate some dimensions of elements to achieve this.
The tabs are built from an Object in $scope, the problem is that the directive that calculates the dimensions is run before the view is fully compiled.

**Plnkr Link:** http://plnkr.co/edit/LOT4sZsNxnfmQ8zHymvw?p=preview

**What i've tried:**

1. loading the template in directive using templateUrl
2. working with transclude
3. to use $last in ng-repeat
4. try to reorder directive and create a dummy directive in every tab to trigger an event

I think that there is some AngularJs event, or property to handle this situation.

Please Guys Help :)

Comment: what's wrong with the `$timeout` you are using? I have been using similar directive, and using `0` for delay, seems to give browser a chance to paint the DOM before code runs in directive

Comment: you are right, but this is workaround not a fix for the problem, when you have complicated directive to build this will end by using timeout multiple times and leads to a mess !!

Comment: is a common usage... get used to  it

Comment: if we simply 'got used to it' for all our computation.. we'd still be typing machine code.

Comment: I need to back this up too. I am inserting directives into a view and they render immediately but the dynamic classes do not. Worse still you get intermediate classes such as your-class-name-add during the adding process. I have experimented with $timeout and I'll need to add a delay as long as 500ms to cover these changes - which is not reliable. The below answer by Alexander represents the most elegant method so far but involves yet another watch... Its becoming unmanageable.

Comment: $timeout no longer works since the release of Angular 1.3 in this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

I make a branch on your plunker, I I think this is what you were looking for

I change your directive to this

```
.directive('onFinishRenderFilters', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then on your HTML I added the directive

```
 <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" on-finish-render-filters>
```

And the last thing I put the code I want to run after the repeat finish

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinished) {
        $scope.tabs = [{
            index: 1,
            title: "Tab 1",
            link: "/tab1/"
        },{
            index: 2,
            title: "Tab 2",
            link: "/tab2/"
        },{
            index: 3,
            title: "Tab 3",
            link: "/tab3/"
        },{
            index: 4,
            title: "Tab 4",
            link: "/tab4/"
        }];

  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TGduPB8FV47QvjjLnFg2?p=preview

Comment: This is good solution as far as you control your ng-repeat and components. In my case, for example, I want to use switchery and I need the exact point where the view is loaded so I can inject it in all rendered controls.

Answer (score 6):

AngularJS does not seem to have reliable post-render callbacks for directives used within ng-repeat. [1]

Maybe you can solve this on CSS level by adding a "responsive" overflow-control element for specific screen widths.

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/SCc45uVhTt8

Update: There now is a way to do this using nested $timeouts. See: http://lorenzmerdian.blogspot.de/2013/03/how-to-handle-dom-updates-in-angularjs.html

Comment: the nested $timeout is what i needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a watch on the actual DOM elements in order to know when your ng-repeat is loaded into the DOM.

Give your ul an id, say #tabs

```
$scope.$watch(
    function () { return document.getElementById('tabs').innerHTML },  
    function(newval, oldval){
        //console.log(newval, oldval);
        //do what you like
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your comments, you already have a solution that works ... and its currently the only solution that I know of: $timeout.

The question is, what do you want to achieve? You want a callback when all rendering is done. Ok, good, but how can angular know this? In a modern app which you are apparently developing when using angular, a rerender can happen all time! A js event can occur where data is loaded from backend, even right after initializing the app, which leads to rerendering. A mouse movement by the user can trigger rerendering of elements, which are even outside of angulars scope because of CSS rules. Any time, a rerender can happen.

So, with these considerations what can angularJS tell you about when rendering is done? It can only tell you, when current $apply and/or $digest chain is processed aka the browser event queue is empty for now. Exactly that is the only information that angularJS knows of. And you use $timeout with a delay of 0 for this.

Yes, you are right, in a bigger appliataion, that can be tricky to a point where its not reliable anymore. But in this case, you should think about how you can solve this in another way. F.i. if a rerender happens later, there must be a cause, like new data that is loaded from the backend. If so, you know when the data is loaded and therefore a rerender happens and therefore you know exactly when you have to update your widths.

Comment: Angualr is responsible for DOM manipulation, therefore, one could expect an event to be fired whenever the DOM manipulation ends. That is a moment in time prior to the browser rendering the changes on screen.

I think that with such an event could be enough for the problem that Abu is having (or others that I'm having right now too).

Comment: like I already wrote: the event you can use for that is $timeout. I would not suggest to use that extensivly, but to design your controller code so that your app knows itself when to update certain elements.